# Not able to add function when using directives

Tags: angularjs, html

http://plnkr.co/edit/JAIyolmqPqO9KsynSiZp?p=preview

How we can add a addChild(tree) function to this code, to add more data to the array. i have changed the template like this

```
'<p>{{ family.name }}{{test }}</p>'+
'<ul>' + 
   '<li ng-repeat="child in family.children">' + 
       '<tree family="child"></tree>' +
   '</li>' +
'</ul>' +
'<button ng-click="addChild()" value="Add">Add</button>'
```

and it is adding the button after each `<ul>`, but when the button is clicked the function not being getting called.
i have this function in the controller

```
$scope.addChild = function (){
    alert();
}
```

what change can i bring ?

Comment: Update your plnkr, it doesn't have the changes you are talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to your plunker.

Basically, what was missing is in the declaration of your `<tree>` tag, a declaration of a method called `addchild`, referring to the parent method (in index.html):

`<tree family="treeFamily" addchild="addChild(family)"></tree>`

Also, in your directive, you need to reference this method as well:

`<button ng-click="addchild({ family : family })" value="Add">Add</button>`

And add in your directive's scope: `addchild: '&'`

Then it should refer to your parent's addChild method, as defined below:

```
$scope.addChild = function (family) {
      if (family)
        family.children.push({ name: "Child", children: []});
    };
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PFRi9EO3GEeXCI7TaVN3?p=preview) for reference

Comment: This is what i was looking for, Thanks.

Comment: can i pass $index to $scope.addChild() function

Comment: I would think so  using { family: family, index: $index } and in the `<tree` declaration, adding parameter index to `addchild="addChild(family, index)"`